# uwp adaptiveGridView throws exception on OneRowMode

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I am having following exception on my adaptivegridview of uwp community toolkit

> "System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>    \r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)\r\n   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.AdaptiveGridView.DetermineOneRowMode()\r\n   at Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.AdaptiveGridView.OnLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"

**XAML**

```
<controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AllVideosGridView" 
                                           OneRowModeEnabled="True"
                                           MaxHeight="260"
                                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                                           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                           ItemClick="AllVideosGridView_ItemClick"
                                           Style="{StaticResource MainGridView}"
    <...data template and other stuff...>
</controls.........>
```

the error occurs due to property OneRowModeEnabled to True, and if I remove that property it works fine and after app runs and then I set this property to true, while app is running then it doesn't show any exception and gridview goes to one row mode as it should.

Also the code behind doesn't matter, because I tried to commend the code behind which initializes the itemsource, but this exception still occurs.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the default `AdaptiveGridView`. Please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue.

Comment: here is a sample and minimal repo with sample project which causes this exception.
https://github.com/touseefbsb/AdaptiveGridViewTest.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you didn't set `ItemHeight` property in `AdaptiveGridView`.

Form the source code of `AdaptiveGridView`, you can find [the following code (L155-L186)](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridView.cs#L155-L186):

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _isLoaded = true;
    DetermineOneRowMode();
}

private void DetermineOneRowMode()
{
    if (_isLoaded)
    {
        var itemsWrapGridPanel = ItemsPanelRoot as ItemsWrapGrid;

        if (OneRowModeEnabled)
        {
            var b = new Binding()
            {
                Source = this,
                Path = new PropertyPath("ItemHeight")
            };

            if (itemsWrapGridPanel != null)
            {
                _savedOrientation = itemsWrapGridPanel.Orientation;
                itemsWrapGridPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            }

            SetBinding(MaxHeightProperty, b);
            ...
```

When `OneRowModeEnabled` set to `True`, it will bind `MaxHeightProperty` to `ItemHeight` property. However, as you didn't set a value to `ItemHeight` property, its value will be `NaN`. That's why you got `Value does not fall within the expected range.` error.

To solve this problem, you can set `ItemHeight` property like the following:

```
 <controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AllVideosGridView"
                                   OneRowModeEnabled="True"
                                   DesiredWidth="260"
                                   ItemHeight="200"
                                   SelectionMode="None"
                                   StretchContentForSingleRow="False"
                                   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Videos, Mode=OneWay}">
    ...
</controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

Comment: is there a way that I can set ItemHieght to Auto? and will it still work?